# Joomla - ставить Denwer, или по отдельности?

Tags: joomla, denwer

Добрый день,

начал заниматься обучаться joomla, и захотел установить все для нее нужное: php, apache, mysql. А сегодня узнал, что существует Денвер.

Как лучше - научиться самому все настраивать руками, или оставить это все дело, поставить Денвер, да углубиться в Joomla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал сервер сконфигурировать вручную. В интернете есть масса пособий по этому с подробным описанием всех параметров. Это как минимум даст понимание процесса и в будущем много вопросов отпадет - это по хорошему, конечно. Хотя начинать обучение с джумылы уже не лучшее решение :-)

Comment: А с чего стоит тогда?) Базовые знания html, css, js, xml, sql присутствуют.

Comment: а лучше покопать фреймворки, понять основы MVC, ООП.

Comment: Люк Веллинг и Лора Томпсон, Разработка Web-приложений на PHP и MySQL. Ну и закреплять навыки :-)

Comment: мне пока не нужен пхп. ООП и МVC знаю

Comment: У меня есть четкое убеждение что человек знающий (не слышавший эти аббревиатуры, а знающий) ООП и MVC не спросит как залить сайт на хостинговую площадку и ставить ли денвер или собирать руками и уж тем более он не подойдет к джумле на пушечный выстрел, чтобы изучить её ;)

Comment: Может слышал? Знать и слышать разные вещи.
Поставь codeigniter или phpcake,zend frame нет? тогда ставь джумлу)
А базовые знания PHP есть?

Comment: раньше был томкат и java. оттуда и знания. изобретать велосипед времени нету

Answer (score 1):

Только не денвер!!! Ставьте AppServ! Лучше, если версии 2.5.9 =)

Comment: АппСерв, поприятнее Денвера будет :-)

Comment: Товарищи холиварщики. По пунктах, пожалуйста, почему то или иное хуже.

Comment: Когда то давно мне он показался удобнее :)

Comment: Лучше просто потому, что не создаёт виртуальный диск. Апач он и в африке апач, но тут можно больше дефолтных настроек проковырять с самого начала

Answer (score 1):

Вы же новичок, поставьте Денвер, станете профессионалом и будете фрилансить, вот тогда уже думайте, что и как откуда вытекает.

Начнете со сложного, будет куча ошибок и неполадок, пропадет интерес, кто знает может у вас талант какой-нибудь в дизайне. ))

Лично у меня Joomla 1.6.5 + XAMPP (был Денвер, чисто любительский на локальном).

Answer (score 1):

Денвер мне понятным оказался. С настройками особо не разбирался, но всё работает по принципу поставил и забыл. Дело ваше.

Answer (score 0):

Ставьте денвер и не парьтесь, чем делать связку apache php mysql.

Comment: А как быть после того, как я все сделаю? Как перенести все, написаное на сервер?

Comment: Перенести сайт? Если сайт, то регистируете хостинг, кидаете по фтп свой сайт и делаете дамп БД и у вас рабочий сайт на хостинге.

Comment: Если что, можете посмотреть видеоуроки Евгения Попова. Профессиональный сайт за 1 час - там все про джумлу и перенос сайта с пк на хостинг есть.

Comment: я пока начал смотреть видео Ивана Юрьева. Собственно, оттуда и узнал про Денвер

Comment: Смотри попова вопросов не будет!

Comment: Печально то как всё... Какие Поповы, Юрьевы? Кто это? Вчерашние студенты с нулевым опытом которые пытаются кого-то учить по тому что прочитали сами в интернете? Читайте нормальную литературу, учитесь, а не видео поделками довольствуйтесь.

Comment: Так то да но начинать с чего то надо же..............

Comment: С начала нужно начинать. Ведь никто не садится писать сочинение, не выучив алфавита и правил языка, тут всё тоже самое.

Comment: Попов это то который на руселлер.ком ,по дизайну можно доверится ему)
Или прямой путь на ИНТУИТ